# Solving inequality with two variables

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I'm looking for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which achives the following:

Note: $m$ is expected to be related to $n$. For example $m=2n$....

$$|n/(1+n^2) - m/(1+m^2)| \ge K. $$    $K > 0$, $K$: constant. An Example: $K = 0.5$

Comment: Is $m$ a real number ?

Comment: @Digitallissimo it's a natural number (although it doesn't matter if you find the m=2n/3 that solves my equation then I could take [m]+1)

Comment: Do you include $0$ in the [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number)?  (ISO-80000-2 says it is, others disagree.)

Comment: yes @EricTowers

Comment: There is no short answer.  What form of long answer would be of use to you?  There seem to be $5$ natural cases in $n$ times four-ish cases in $a$.

Comment: n and K are given, so this is an inequality with one variable. The variable is m.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in \mathbb N, K > 0$. Is there $m \in \mathbb N$ such that the inequality

$$ \left \vert \frac{n}{1+n^2} - \frac{m}{1+m^2}\right \vert \geq K$$
holds ?

If $n = 0$

We must have $\left \vert \frac{m}{1+m^2} \right \vert  \geq K$. WLOG assume $ m > 0.$ On can show that the function $f: x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is positive continuous increasing on $(0,1)$ and decreasing on $(1, + \infty)$ so $f(m)$ takes with $m \in \mathbb N$ takes its values in $(0,f(1)]$. Therefore

$$ 0< K \leq f(m) \leq f(1) = 0.5.$$

In order for $m$ to exist we must have $K \in (0,0.5]$ and we can then take $m = 1$ as the $m$ we're looking for.

If $n \geq 1:$

- and $ K \leq \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ then we can just take $m = 0$.
- and  $ K >\frac{n}{n^2+ 1}:$We start our search by considering $m \geq n \geq 1$. Since $x/(x^2+1)$ strictly decreasing for $x \geq 1$ we have 
  $$ \left \vert \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} - \frac{m}{m^2+1}\right \vert = \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} - \frac{m}{m^2+1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}.$$
  But then we would have $K \leq \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} < K$ so if $m$ exists it must be strictly less than $n$.

For $1 \leq m < n$ we must have

$$\left \vert \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} - \frac{m}{m^2+1}\right \vert =\left \vert \frac{m}{m^2+1} - \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \right \vert = \frac{m}{m^2+1} - \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}.$$

So if we have $K > \frac{1}{2} - \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ there is no such $m$. If $ K \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ then we can take $ m =1.$ Putting all of this together

$$m=
\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } K \leq 0.5 , n = 0 \\
 0 & \text{if } 0 < K \leq \frac{n}{n^2+1} \\
 1 & \text{if } \frac{n^2}{n^2 + 1}< K \leq \frac{1}{2}- \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \\
 \not \exists & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

which can be rewritten as

$$m = 
\begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } 0 < K \leq \frac{n}{n^2+1} \\
 1 & \text{if } \frac{n^2}{n^2 + 1}< K \leq \frac{1}{2}- \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \\
 \not \exists & \text{if } K > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}
\end{cases}.$$